# spring autowiring not working

Tags: java, spring

Hi,
I am using spring 3.0 with Quartz in a scheduler class.  I have created the application context by

```
private static final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext;
static {
    applicationContext = new
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/applicationContext.xml");
}
```

The problem is that none of the `@Autowired` beans actually get auto-wired, so I have to manually set dependencies like this:

```
<bean class="com.spr.service.RegistrationServiceImpl" id="registrationService">
    <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
</bean>
```

Example of where I'm using `@Autowired`:

```
public class RegistrationService {
   @AutoWired private UserService userService;
   // setter for userService;
}

public class UserService{
   // methods
}
```

I also made sure to enable the annotation configuration in my Spring config:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean id="registrationSevice" class="RegistrationService"/>
<bean id="userService" class="UserService"/>
```

Why is `@Autowired` not working for me?

Comment: Tip: It's a better paradigm to autowire via the constructor:
`private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public ResgistrationService(UserService userService) { // setter }`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You haven't provided the UserService class source code so I can't be sure about your problem. Looks like the UserService class is missing a 'stereotype' annotation like @Component or @Service. You also have to configure the Spring classpath scanning using the following configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <!-- Add your classes base package here -->          
     <context:component-scan base-package="your.package"/>

   </beans>
```

Your beans must include one of the Spring stereotype annotations like:

```
package your.package;

@Service
public class UserService{
}
```

Comment: I doubt whether the @Service annotation is required, anyways I will give a try.

Comment: @prassee the @Component (or sub) Annotation is required to create a bean for this class. You can do this with XML too, but I believe this is not want you want - or is it?

Comment: @Ralph yes. I worked on spring mvc 3.0 in which the applicationContext.xml have the <context:component-scan> and the controllers are annotated with @controllers , the dependent objects are annotated with @Autowired Service service. So I was expecting the same here. I will try with @Service for my service classes

Comment: @prassee, @Component, @Service, @Repository are equals (for this concern), Try @Autowired(required=true) or @Ressouce, to make sure that Spring find the required resource, and not leave it empty because it does not find it.

Answer (score 8):

Atlast i got it resolved by adding the

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package"/>
```

in my applicationContext.xml. Thank u all for your support.